# How to flush NLog Loggers when using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging LoggerFactory

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I'm wondering about a little think concerning ILoggerFactory abstraction of microsoft when used with NLog.

My program currently instantiate a factory manually before configuring and running an IHost to catch program args errors or email sending errors, here is a simplified version of my Program class:

```
ApplicationScope applicationScope;
ExecutionScope executionScope;

var loggerFactory = GetLoggerFactory();
try
{
    if (args.Length != 2)
        throw new ArgumentException("The number of args program input parameters isn't valid");
    if (!Enum.TryParse(args[0], out applicationScope) || !Enum.IsDefined(applicationScope))
        throw new ArgumentException($"The provided input program value: {args[0]}, isn't valid for {nameof(ApplicationScope)}", nameof(args));
    if (!Enum.TryParse(args[1], out executionScope) || !Enum.IsDefined(executionScope))
        throw new ArgumentException($"The provided input program value: {args[1]}, isn't valid for {nameof(ExecutionScope)}", nameof(args));

    // Configure Host container.
    IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
        {
            // Clear default log Providers and add Nlog.
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddNLog();
        })
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.ConfigureAllServices(ExecutionScope);
        }).Build();

    return await host.RunBatchAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
    logger.LogCritical(ex, "An error occured during execution at {Date}, with following message: {ExceptionDescription}", DateTime.Now.ToString("g"), ex.Message);

    var option = GetConfiguredMailOptions();

    if (option != null)
        await new MailService(option, loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MailService> 
            ()).SendLogEmailAsync("subject", "message");
    else
        logger.LogError("The mail configuration isn't properly set, check the appsettings.json.");

    return 1;
}
finally
{
    // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid 
segmentation fault on Linux)
    loggerFactory.Dispose();
    LogManager.Shutdown();
}

static ILoggerFactory GetLoggerFactory()
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings. 
        {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true, 
        reloadOnChange: true)
      .Build();
      return LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddNLog(config));
      //return LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromSection(config).GetCurrentClassLogger();
 }

static IOptions<MailOptions>? GetConfiguredMailOptions()
{
     var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings. 
      {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true, 
      reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();
    MailOptions? option = config.GetSection(MailOptions.SectionName).Get<MailOptions>();
    return option != null ? Options.Create(option) : null;
}
```

My concern is about the finally block, in case of using the factory, do i need to call the NLog LogManager.Shutdown() to properly clean logging resources before exiting the app or disposing the logger factory is enough?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The standalone Microsoft LoggerFactory (created without using host-builder) will dispose all added logging providers when it is disposed.

The NLog LoggingProvider will by default not shutdown NLog LogFactory on dispose, but it can be enabled by specifiying `NLogProviderOptions` with `ShutdownOnDispose = true` (As parameter to `AddNLog`).

Since you have tried to isolate NLog-configuration inside `GetLoggerFactory`, then I suggest using `ShutdownOnDispose = true`, and remove the explicit `LogManager.Shutdown();` in the `finally`-block.

If only using NLog as LoggingProvider, then for optimal performance then you could just return the light-weight `NLogLoggerFactory` from `GetLoggerFactory`.